# Computation of pg_trgm similarity

Tags: postgresql

I would like to know what kind of similarity function is used in the case of PostgreSQL `pg_trgm` extension. My initial assumption was that it computes the similarity of two strings s1 and s2 using the following formula:

```
sim(s1, s2) = |G3(s1) ⋂ G3(s2)| / max(|G(s1)|, |G(s2)|)
```

where G3 is a set of 3-grams for a string. I tried several examples and it seems that the computation is somehow different in PostgreSQL.

```
create extension pg_trgm;

create table doc (
    word text
);

insert into doc values ('bbcbb');

select *, similarity(word, 'bcb') from doc;
```

The above example returns 0.25. However,

```
G3('bbcbb') = {##b, #bb, bbc, bcb, cbb, bb#, b##}
G3('bcb') = {##b, #bc, bcb, cb#, b##}
|G3(s1) ⋂ G3(s2)| = 3
max(|G(s1)|, |G(s2)|) = 7
```

therefore the `sim` formula does not return 0.25. What is the correct formula?

Comment: Why don't you just check [the source code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/master/contrib/pg_trgm)?

Answer (score 3):

I think u need to check this:
[PostgreSQL, trigrams and similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43156987/postgresql-trigrams-and-similarity)

Summ:

```sql
SELECT show_trgm('bbcbb'), show_trgm('bcb')
```

*'bbcbb' = {"  b"," bb","bb ",bbc,bcb,cbb}


'bcb' = {"  b"," bc",bcb,"cb "}*

'bbcbb' -> 6 element
'bcb' -> 4 element

```
SELECT UNNEST(show_trgm('bbcbb')) INTERSECT SELECT UNNEST(show_trgm('bcb'))
```

Result: 2 elements are common

```
SELECT UNNEST(show_trgm('bbcbb')) UNION SELECT UNNEST(show_trgm('bcb'))
```

Result: 8 elements

Similarity 2/8 =  0.25

UPDATE:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/pgtrgm.html

In the F.31.1. Trigram (or Trigraph) Concepts section

There is a note says:

"...Each word is considered to **have two spaces prefixed** and **one space suffixed** when determining the set of trigrams contained in the string..."

Comment: Ok, it makes sense. I do not understand why `ps_trgm` does not generate the last trigram, but now the computation is correct. Thanks.

Comment: The formula from the source is `count / (len1 + len2 - count)`, where `count` is the number of common trigrams and `len1` and `len2` are the number of trigrams for the strings. That is exactly the same as what you say.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks that makes the computation even more clear